# How do I view thrown errors in Meteor methods?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to see instances of Meteor.Error as well as anything else that is thrown. On the server side, I'm looking at what is printed out to the console after running the `meteor` command (in development on localhost:3000). On the client, I'm looking at the JS console.

When a Meteor.Error is thrown on the client, I see it on the client console. When a Meteor.Error is thrown on the server, I see nothing on either side. When other types of errors are thrown on either side (for example, `assert(false)` with the mrt assert package), I see it on neither side.

Answer (score 5):

It depends where you throw the `Meteor.Error`, it needs a context to give to the client.

If you throw a `Meteor.Error` in a method you will see it come back in the `err` of the callback of the client side call. e.g

Server side

```
Meteor.methods({
    'crashme':function() {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Error Title", "details", "more details");
    }
});
```

Client side

```
Meteor.call("crashme", function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    //--> Prints the thrown error
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works with Meteor.Error on the server. It also shows "Internal server error [500]" for `assert` on the server. How can I see on the server side the full text of the `assert` error? Also, it does not show `assert` errors that occur on the client - how can I see those?